# "You can’t edit this Email Template ..." during update unlocked package

Tags: email-template, package

I created two versions of my package. In the first version, I added the Email Template LWC `MyTemplate_1668678338227`. Next, I created a second version with **no changes**.
Right now, when I try to install the second (the first one is already installed) version of my package on scratch org I got the error:

`1) (MyFolder/MyTemplate_1668678338227) You can’t edit this Email Template because it’s from a managed package. To make an editable copy, clone the template., Details: MyFolder/MyTemplate_1668678338227: You can’t edit this Email Template because it’s from a managed package. To make an editable copy, clone the template.`

How to correct pack Email Template in package?

Comment: Hi @hsd, I have the same issue as yours. Did you manage to fix the issue ?

Comment: No directly. The only possible way for me was to remove problematic templates before installing the new package version. When you have CI/CD you can automatize it by `sfdx`